# Why can't I access port 80 when I can access port 8080?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, web-deployment

I have deployed my web application via AWS EC2. I have made inbound rules as below.

[Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyQFI.png)

I can now access through `myIP:8080` but I get an error with `myIP` or `myIP:80`. The error message I get is: `This site can’t be reached. refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection. Checking the proxy and the firewall. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

What am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: So you have some web server software installed on the EC2 instance and configured to listen on port `8080`. Do you also have something running on the EC2 instance that is configured to listen on port `80`?

Comment: @MarkB Nope, there's nothing running other than this one. Actually, I've managed to figure it out by port forwarding, but not sure why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue by port forwarding with the following command:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Comment: What you have done above is  "instead of getting in the driving seat from the driverside, you are getting inside the backseat from passenger side, get off from the driver side and then get into the driving seat".